# Override WKS_FILE for SD partition layout

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm customizing var-som-mx6 of variscite and I can't figure out how I can override WKS_FILE variable because I want to change my sd card layout without creating new MACHINE or new IMAGE...
Any help to do this?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WKS_FILE_forcevariable` Using this in image.bb works.